# Can a template argument be an expression?

Tags: c++, templates, expression

I want to do this:

```
template<T>
bool AssertThrows() {
  try {
    T; // T is an expression, so evaluate it here
    return false;
  } catch(...) {
    return true;
  }
}

int main() {
  bool throws = !AssertThrows<5 + 2>();
  return !throws;
}
```

But this does not work: all I get is these compiler errors:

```
$ clang++ a.cc
a.cc:1:10: error: unknown type name 'T'
template<T>
         ^
a.cc:4:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'T'
    T; // T is an expression
    ^
2 errors generated.
```

Is it possible to have an expression as a template parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case a function taking another function to simulate pass by name could work if you don't mind

```
template<typename T>
bool AssertThrows(T t) {
  try {
    t(); // t contains an expression, so evaluate it here
    return false;
  } catch(...) {
    return true;
  }
}

int main() {
  bool throws = !AssertThrows([]{ 5 + 2; });
  return !throws;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Templates are processed at compile time, and that means that you can only use *constant expressions*, none of which can throw, so the simple answer is that you cannot do what you want there.

While I am against macros in most contexts, this is one of those few places where they make sense, and if you look at test frameworks you will find that macros ar the common solution for this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

A template parameter can be a constant expression, as David pointed out.  Is this what you were after?

```
template<int Expr>
bool AssertThrows() {
  try {
    Expr; // Expr is a constant expression that 'is' an int, so evaluate it here
    return false;
  } catch(...) {
    return true;
  }
}

int main() {
  bool throws = !AssertThrows<5 + 2>();
  return !throws;
}
```